# No FM/AM audio output on car radio, RDS and CD working

Tags: audio, kia, picanto

Strange issue with my 2011 Kia Picanto.

When on AM or FM while the radio can scan and find stations, tune to them and display the RDS data for them, there is no sound output. At first it started off occasionanly working but now it doesn't at all.

It's not the antenna as I've checked that this is connected, and the radio still receives and displays RDS data. It's not the speakers as they work when the CD player is being used.

Any ideas what it could be? Maybe a dead capacitor or something somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!